# При клике в массив добавляются не все значения

Tags: javascript

Есть `input`, куда вводиться значение и при нажатии на кнопку, происходит обработка клика. При этом при каждом клике, значение `input` должно записаться в массив `values`, но почему-то записывается только первое значение, а остальные нет. В чем проблема?

```
let values = [];
let typeName = document.querySelector('#type_user_name');
let addUser = document.querySelector('#add_user');

addUser.addEventListener('click', () => {

    values.push(typeName.value);

});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: @Grundy, ну не дубликат же...

Comment: @Qwertiy, 100% дубликат

Comment: *"This is not an argument!" "Yes, it is."* Monty Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    let values = [];
    let typeName = document.querySelector('#type_user_name');
    let addUser = document.querySelector('#add_user');
    
    addUser.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
        values.push(typeName.value);
        console.log(values); // output inside click
    });
```

```html
<input id="type_user_name" type="text"/>
<button id="add_user">Click</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Скажите пожалуйста, а почему в глобальной области значения не показывались?

Comment: @AlexanderK потому что Вы выводили массив, не дожидаясь нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Правильнее использовать форму и обрабатывать событие `submit`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кхм, кхм... Какая форма? Какой submit?

Comment: @Igor, обернуть инпут с кнопкой в форму и подписываться на её событие submit. Тогда enter будет работать.